# Div element not expanding to hold HTML text

Tags: jquery, css

*HTML:*

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="HeaderTitle">
        This is a very long title which should should force HeaderTitle to expand.
    </div>
</div>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#HeaderTitle').mouseover(function(e) {
        var distanceToMove = $(this).width() - $('#Header').width();
        var timeToTakeMoving = 30 * distanceToMove;

        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + distanceToMove + "px"
        }, timeToTakeMoving);
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        });
    });
});​
```

*JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/QQtp6/7/

I am hoping to have the div 'HeaderTitle' expand to hold the text inside of it. This would allow me to scroll the text on mouseover. Why does the div not hold its contents?

EDIT: The goal here is not to have all the text visible. I want to display a portion of the text in a fixed-width div and then scroll the text through that div.

Example:

If the text was: "FULL TEXT HERE" I would expect only "FULL TE" to show until mouseover. At that point I would expect it to transition to "TEXT HERE" with FULL being hidden off to the LHS.

EDIT2: I believe the solution is to use a span instead of a div for HeaderTitle. One moment.

EDIT3: posted solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing my nested div element, HeaderTitle, to a span:

http://jsfiddle.net/QQtp6/20/

```
<div id="Header">
    <span id="HeaderTitle">
        This is a very long title which should should force HeaderTitle to expand.
    </span >
</div>​

$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#HeaderTitle').mouseover(function (e) {
        var distanceToMove = $(this).width() - $('#Header').width();

        var timeToTakeMoving = 30 * distanceToMove; 

        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "-" + distanceToMove + "px" }, timeToTakeMoving);
            }).mouseout(function (e) {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({ marginLeft: "0px" });
            });
});

#Header
{
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#HeaderTitle
{    
    white-space: nowrap; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing that `overflow:hidden` will expand the div all the way.

Changing that `overflow:auto` and it should expand to 100px as you have set it and show a scroller.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/QQtp6/13/

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your response. Could you please refer to my edit? It seems my question was misunderstood. I understand how I could display all the text. I am trying to make a 'ticker' where the text transitions through the div.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width and then you're stating to hide any data that overflows the fixed width:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

The purpose of that attribute is to hide data to preserve the desired formatting.  If you want the data to be shown then you do not want to apply the `overflow` attribute.

If it has to stay at the width of 100px then you will need to modify the attribute to `overflow: auto;`, which will add scrollbars so that the content can still be viewed within the container.

Answer (score 0):

Both `overflow: hidden` and `width: 100px` are preventing what you want. A div with a fixed width won't stretch, and the overflow rule then hides the text that overflows. Just remove one of the rules, preferably the overflow one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem this is happening is because "HeaderTitle" is of same width as "Header"-(padding). 
I have got three solutions for you.

1. In case you know the width of the child element.

   .HeaderTitle
   {
       width: 666px;//Width of child element,  Ex. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QQtp6/65/)
   }
2. You can also float your div which will force it as small as possible, but you'll need to use a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) if anything inside your div is floating.

   .HeaderTitle
   {
       float: left;// Ex. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QQtp6/66/)
   }
3. Use of span instead of div. Since span doesn't show the odd behaviour as does using div, if your designs allow you can use span. Ex. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QQtp6/67/)